# Multi Thread in web service for asenkron call

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have a web service, web page and queue mechanism. I want the web page to use the web service in order to connect and listen to my queue.

When a new event comes to the queue it should trigger `myfunction` and then continue to watch the queue in background.

What is the right approach to do this in a web service or web application in c#?

Comment: http://signalr.net/

Comment: You shouldn't multithread within an ASP.NET site. It's not designed for that. Instead, you can have a background process such as a Windows Service that's job is to process items off the queue. If you need to update your UI based on that, then have your background process connect to SignalR hosted in the site.

Comment: Actually I dont want to update UI process,I want to start a thread in background and want to keep this thread all in application runtime and it works in background in web project